# Python - Get sorted list of user-defined classes

Tags: python, class, list, user-defined-types

I have a class:

```
class Prediction():
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.start = l[0]
        self.end = l[1]
        self.score = l[2]
```

And a list, where each element is a `Prediction`. It's aptly named `predictions`.

I want to sort `predictions` by the `start` attribute of the `Prediction` class.

Something like this:

```
predictions_start_order = sorted(predictions, key=start)
```

Which doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

```
predictions_start_order = sorted(predictions, key=lambda x: x.start)
```

Comment: If you're going to use a key function, use `operator.attrgetter('start')` instead of a `lambda`.

Comment: @agf Why ? Actually I find this notation a lot less readable.

Comment: @agf I don't like the fact that operator.attrgetter requires an additional import. I think both solutions are readable.

Comment: For what it's worth, `operator.attrgetter('start')` is faster than `lambda x: x.start`.

Answer (score 2):

The `key` argument to [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) takes a *function*, not an attribute. What you're looking for is:

```
class Prediction():
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.start = l[0]
        self.end = l[1]
        self.score = l[2]

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.start < other.start
```

This will allows `sorted` to order an iterable of instances of this class automatically.

Only `__lt__` is actually needed for sorting in Python, but [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends you implement all of the rich comparisons or use the [`total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator.

Comment: FWIW, PEP 8 recommends defining all six rich comparisons rather than relying on the implementation using __lt__.  Alternatively, you can use functools.total_ordering to fill-in the missing methods.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Already included that based on your previous comment on another of my posts :) Just wanted to get the core answer up before I added details.

Comment: I like this solution in the case where you are always going to be sorting by one field. For example, if `start` was the key for the `Prediction` class, I would prefer this method.